# Hosting two SSL sites (different host name) on same server with different certificates and without ports (i.e. 443)

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-on-prem, iis, alternate-access-mapping, ssl

We have a SharePoint site https://example.com hosted on port 443.

There is another site https://anotherexample.com that should be hosted on same server and without port (i.e. 443).

Both the certificates are issued to different host names (i.e. not wildcard certificate).

How can I achieve above scenario?

Any help is much appreciated!

**Edit:** I'm working on IIS 8.
Is there a need to allocate second IP address to the server or there is a fix through SNI (How can we achieve this scenario using SNI)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS6 does not have the capability of using [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). You need to allocate a second IP address to the server and bind your IIS sites to specific IP:Port combinations.

Comment: Appreciate your response.
I have edited the post that I'm working on IIS 8, so is this possible without allocating second IP address? If yes, how?

Comment: As i was working on IIS 8, i have used SNI to bind the sites on port 443 and it worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices in this scenario

1. Get the dedicated IP address for the 2nd site and Bind it to IIS along with Certficate
2. You can use different port then 443 and Bind the certificate on it. then URL will be https://anotherexample.com:7513 (any custom port you pick)

1st method we implemented and working flawlessly.

Comment: The requirement is to not have port in the URL i.e. it should be like https://anotherexample.com so I cannot go with second scenario. 
As I'm working on IIS 8, is there a possibility to achieve this without allotting second IP address and with using SNI (How?)?

Comment: yes, please check this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sambetts/2015/02/13/running-multiple-sharepoint-ssl-websites-on-separate-ssl-certificates-using-server-name-indication/